# Google OAuth 2 authorization in android application - Error: unsupportedt_response_type

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, xamarin, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate my android app with google login with the following :

```
     var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            clientId: CLIENTID,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://localhost"));


        auth.Completed += (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs eventArgs) => {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
                App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke ();

                App.SaveToken (eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"],App.Log_type.google);
            } else {
                ////Cancelled
        }
        };
```

There is no client secret for android in the google developer console. After the login page, it shows a screen with error ***unsupported_response_type** . I am struggling to fix this error and have no idea how to do it even after a lot of googling and searching. Could you point me in the right direction and tell me what am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty straight forward. Your response type on the request is wrong. It should be "token" to that particular URL. If you are using the implicit grant flow. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent).